# Writing Xml fails. Library not found although it is in maven

Tags: java, xml, maven, war, woodstox

I am generating an Xml-File. This works in development, but not on my test server. The code to generate it looks like this:

```
JacksonXmlModule xmlModule = new JacksonXmlModule();
xmlModule.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper(xmlModule);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.writeValue(xmlFile, myObject);
```

I have the current version of woodstox as a dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have a dependency for `jackson-core` and `jackson-dataformat-xml` (and `jackson-datatype-jsr310`) in there.

This works fine in development, but when I'm deploying the code as a war file and start it with the jetty server on a test machine this throws this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Underlying Stax XMLStreamWriter 
(of type com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl) does not implement 
Stax2 API natively and is missing method 'writeRaw': this breaks functionality such as
indentation that relies on it. You need to upgrade to using compliant Stax implementation
like Woodstox or Aalto
```

I verified that the war file does have the library in it. I found it unter `ROOT.war\WEB-INF\lib\woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar`

So this leaves me clueless to why I get this error.
To me it seems like woodstox is not used and therefore java falls back to Stax1, although woodstox is in the archive.

Any suggestions what might happening here or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Ever got solution to this?  I am having same issue

Comment: @pixel It might have been a conflicting dependency. I think had both woodstox-core and jackson-dataformat-xml.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have another Stax implementation (`sjsxp`?) that gets registered instead of Woodstox. Since this is Sun implementation, bundled with JDK (but also at least earlier available as separate jar), it could also mean that you are actually not including Woodstox.

There is a way to explicitly specify `XMLInputFactory` to use with Jackson XML module, when constructing `XmlMapper`. By doing that you could more reliably specify factory to use, and not relying on automatic registration of Stax implementation.

Comment: I dont have a dependency for sjsxp in my pom.xml. Also woodstox-core is in the packaged war. I do use jackson-dataformat-xml, but even when I remove that, I still get the same problem.
I added code to the question showing how I use it. I am using JacksonXmlModule already.

Comment: You do not need to add dependency, since, -- as I said in my answer -- sjsxp is bundled in JDK, that is, included already. You can not not have it. And the exception specifically indicates that is being used (see the class name). The fact Woodstox is also included does not necessarily fix the problem because of Service Provider Information based lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this dependency(com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl) in your project and exclude this dependency from your pom.xml.

Example:-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>some.artifect.id</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>Group id of com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl</groupId>
                <artifactId>and artifect id</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```